# understanding behavior of mapping to an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

When does `map` modify an array in place? I know the preferred way to iterate over an array is with a list comprehension, but I'm preparing an algorithm for ipyparallel, which apparently uses the `map` function. Each row of my array is a set of model inputs, and I want to use `map`, ultimately in parallel, to run the model for each row. I'm using Python 3.4.5 and Numpy 1.11.1.  I need these versions for compatibility with other packages.

This simple example creates a list and leaves the input array intact, as I expected.

```
grid = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
grid

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

def f(g):
    return g + 1

n = list(map(f, grid))
grid

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

But when the function modifies a slice of the input row, the array is modified in place.  Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
def f(g):
    g[:2] = g[:2] + 1
    return g

n = list(map(f, grid))
grid

array([[ 1,  2,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 6,  7,  7,  8,  9],
       [11, 12, 12, 13, 14],
       [16, 17, 17, 18, 19],
       [21, 22, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Comment: In the second case, you are taking a slice, which is a view into the input array. So, when you are adding`1` to it and storing/assigning it back, it gets stored into the original array. Google for "NumPy view vs copy" for more info on it. In the first case, you are not doing any assignment, so no change for input array in that case.

Comment: Thank you.  I had thought that by iterating through the array, a copy of each row would be passed to the function.

Comment: `[f(g) for g in grid]` and `for g in grid: f(g)` both do the same thing.  All these, including `map` iterate on the first dimension of `grid`, yielding a view.  No one makes a copy.  You get the same behavior if you iterate on a list of lists (such as `grid.tolist()`) and perform an in-place action (e.g. `g.append(100)`).